# Mongodb | Romove object from document's array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried to remove an object from document array but something not working:

This is my object:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b487aa1427e5a1edc1cdbac"),
    "location" : {
        "latitude" : 0,
        "longitude" : 0
    },
    "email" : "ran@gmail.com",
    "firstName" : "Ran",
    "lastName" : "Alcobi",
    "interests" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b49a44bc3b19929b098547e")
    ],
}
```

I removed Interest from the interests collection and I need that the interest will be removed from the Interests array of the user:

this is my code:

```
 router.delete('/:id',  (req, res) => {
    var id = req.params.id;

    if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }

    Interest.findOneAndRemove({
      _id: id,
    }).then((interest) => {
      if (!interest) {
        return res.status(404).send();
      }
      User.update(
        {$pull:       
           {interests: {$in : interest._id} }
        },
        {multi: true},
      ).then((user) => {

        console.log(user);

      res.send({interest});
    }).catch((e) => {
      res.status(400).send();
    });

    });
  });
```

Thanks a lot for helpers. I would be happy to know what is my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) in wrong parameter of update query... In update query first parameter is for filter and second parameter is for update operation... So you have to first filter with [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) and then [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) from the interest array...

So, finally you need to do something like this

```
User.update(
  { interests: { $in : [interest._id] } },
  { $pull: { interests: interest._id } }
  { multi: true },
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Anthony, also need a little fix: {interests: {$in : [ interest._id] }}

Comment: @RanAlcobi Yes made it